# jQuery GET Method test execution

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to test that the data are successfully send with GET method or wait 1 or 2 second, but it seems that the setTimeOut function doesn't work. And when I make an alert instate of setTimeOut it works.

```
<form class="form-inline"  method = "post" action="form1.php" id="formemail">
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-7 col-sm-12 clearfix">
                                <div class="form-group desk-pull-left">
                                    <label class="sr-only"  for="NewsletterEmail">Email address</label>
                                    <input type="email" size="60" class="form-control" id="NewsletterEmail" name="NewsletterEmail" placeholder="Enter email">
                                    <span id="response">
                                                                                </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-5 col-sm-7 clearfix">
                                <div class="form-group desk-pull-left">
                                    <input type="submit" value="CONTINUE" class="desk-pull-right btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-continue">
                                </div>      
                            </div>
                        </form>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {

        $( "#formemail" ).submit(function( event ) {
            if ( $( "#NewsletterEmail" ).val().length > 0  ) {
                var email = $( "#NewsletterEmail" ).val();
                var dataString = "pswd=NJGBUlS5y&url=proe.net&stamp=2014-11-17 21:40:00&ip=40.40.40.1&email=aaaaa@aaaa.com";
                $.ajax({
                      type: "GET",
                      url: "https://www.acads.com/promox/livefeed.php",
                      data: dataString,
                      dataType: "script",
                      cache: false,

                      success: function(){
                                alert('successs');
                             },
                      error:  function(){
                                alert('failed');
                             }      
                    });
                     //$('body').append('<h1 ></h1>');
                     //console.log('hello');

                    setTimeout( function () { 
                        $( "#formemail" ).submit();
                    }, 1000);
                    return;

            }else{
                alert( "Email field is Required!" );
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });

    });

    </script>
```

Please can you have a solution for this?

Comment: For `form.submit();` : `form` is defined somewhere? Probably not...

Comment: i forget to define it, but even i change it by $('form') still not working....

Comment: Add alert (or console.log) to your setTimeout callback. Maybe it was called many times but you requests are hang in pending state. BTW as your code acts form _should_ be send infinite times.

Comment: Yeah, actually that URL fails on timeout after 1.3 min pending. And after that `error` callback will be called. Just take a look to 'network' tab in developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your ajax.

```
async : false
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all learn the power of developers console ([the better one is in Chorme](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) but similar tools are in Firefox and in IE)

Second, add the `error` callback to your ajax call, not only `success`. Just to pick unsuccessful requests.

And finally the `form` variable used in timeout call is not defined.

Comment: i put error callback, but no changes that doesn't work

Comment: he already mentioned in the comment that he is using $('form').which is correct until and unless he is having two form on same page.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this :

```
setTimeout( function () {

    $('#formId_searchform').submit();
}, 500);
```